# LinkedIn login for Web Pages

Tags: web, linkedin-api

I'm looking to develop a web page for myself, basically listing my resume, past work, and posting up projects i've worked on and such.  Is there a way to use a LinkedIn login process for my site, where the user must have a linkedin account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1244.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the [LinkedIn API](http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis) to handle this for you. It uses [OAuth](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1243) as it's authentication method.

Answer (score 1):

Visit LinkedIn developer section: https://developer.linkedin.com/

This link is also helpful to implement LinkedIn login http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best source of information is the following:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin

You don't want to have to mess with the complexity of OAuth for your use case, most likely, so this actually would be the best course to allow you to authenticate users easily.

If you have questions, don't hesitate to reach out on our forums. We are always more than happy to help!

-Jeremy